# Scheduling Airflow timezone-aware dags based on my local timezone

Tags: timezone, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

I have a timezone-aware airflow dag, and I want to schedule it 9 am everyday in my local timezone. But what I see is that ds, next_ds and data_interval_end template variables are all in UTC. That changes the run date for my dags.

At 9 am Sydney time today (UTC+11), UTC time is 1 day behind (10 pm yesterday). That means I get the date wrong in both ds and next_ds vars. How do I workaround that? I want to be able to schedule dags in my local timezone and get the correct date for today, not having to calculate UTC times.

This problem can be still be handled programmatically in Python code, because you can play around with the dates, but for SQL templates if I want to use {{ ds }} or {{ next_ds }} as partition for my data, it translates to the wrong dates.

So if I am running the dag on 29th at 9 am Sydney time (UTC + 11), this is what I get in the Airflow template variables:

> [2023-11-29, 13:08:12 AEDT] {{subprocess.py:93}} INFO - Next_ds is 2023-11-28.
> [2023-11-29, 13:08:12 AEDT] {{subprocess.py:93}} INFO - ds is 2023-11-27.
> [2023-11-29, 13:08:12 AEDT] {{subprocess.py:93}} INFO - data_interval_end is 2023-11-28T22:00:00+00:00.

The documentation says the date intervals are always calculated in UTC even though you have set Airflow to your local timezone.

How do you handle that, specially for SQL templates?

Comment: Can you show us the code that sets the `start_date` of your DAG please ?
Also, have a look at [DAG Runs #data-interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#data-interval) and try to use [Time Zone aware DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags)

Comment: Yes already doing that, the dag is timezone aware, and I can confirm that by printing the date in the logs.
I am setting the start date as this inside a default_args dictionary: 
'start_date': pendulum.datetime(2023, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, tz="Australia/Sydney")

Comment: Can you provide in your question the `start_date` and the `schedule` you use please ?
It seems the start_date you provided is set to run at midnight. There might be a mistake during declaration.
Also, what `version` of Airflow are you using ?

Comment: @vdolez start_date is set as: 'start_date': pendulum.datetime(2023, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, tz="Australia/Sydney")
And I am using MWAA on AWS, Airflow version 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

you can access the dag timezones in airflow macros. See below.

DECLARE @ds DATE = '{{ dag_run.data_interval_end.astimezone(dag.timezone) | ds }}';

Comment: Where would I define these? Can I define and access them in SQL template?
I have a SQL like this: 

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE rundate = '{{ next_ds }}';

Comment: Yes, that snippet was from one of my SQL files where I'm declaring a variable and using multiple times in the SQL statement.

Comment: The solution didn't work for me. Airflow gave me a template assertion error
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'ds'.